# WooCommerce list view

Tags: wordpress, listview, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site with WooCommerce installed,

The problem I'm having is on the shop page the products are by default shown as a GRID (side by side), there's a button to switch from the default GRID mode to LIST mode; but for every new client that comes on the site, they would have to manually change it!

I'd like to permanently change the default view from GRID to LIST for every person that comes on the site, but I can't find any way to do this in the code.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how to do this?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to [so]. You may have a better chance of having it answered if you contact the developer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin that can do this for you: http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-grid-list-toggle

After installing the plugin go to your dashboard: Woocommerce -> Settings -> product -> Scroll to the bottom of the page and there is an option called `Default catalog view`, change that from Grid to List.
There will be an option for users on the shop page to change the view from List to Grid. To hide this option add the following to the CSS:

```
.gridlist-toggle 
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem.

This is my solution how to PERNAMENTLY force WooCommerce to show product catalog only as List View.

JS

```
// This will remove class="grid" on page load and add class="list" to your product view

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.browse-view ul#products').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
});
```

JS -- Test with Woocommerce v4.0.1

```
// -- Last Rev. (2020-04) -- 
jQuery(function($){
     $('.woocommerce ul.products').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
});
```

CSS

```
/* This will hide grid/list switcher in toolbar*/
.view-mode{display:none!important;}
```

Comment: Hi, I which files can I place this code to remove grid view and make list view the default? I would also like to do the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution can switch grid to list view as default on **products page**.
You can try this:

1. Connect to your FTP/public_html/wp-content/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/global/
2. Edit wrapper-start.php
3. You will see this code

   ```
   $shop_view = shopme_get_meta_value('shop_view');
   if (empty($shop_view)) { $shop_view = 'view-grid'; }
   if (!empty( $shop_view ) ) { $wrapper_classes[] = $shop_view; }
   ```
4. Replace "view-grid" to "list_view_products"

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this is use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gridlist-view-for-woocommerce/
After install go to settings **WooCommerce -> Grid/List View**
In *Buttons tab* change **Default style** to **List** and uncheck all in **Buttons display**
In *Products Count tab* uncheck **Use products count**